Small antenna radiation efficiency and bandwidh trade-off
Theoretical part:
Small antenna radiation efficiency (RE) and bandwidth (BW) trade-off
When designing small antennas, there is a well-known trade-off between RE and BW. This trade-off arises due to fundamental physical limitations related to the antenna size relative to the wavelength at which it operates.
Small antennas typically have a high-quality factor (Q), and this high Q results in a narrow BW because the antenna is highly resonant at a specific frequency but not over a wide range.
Therefore achieving good impedance matching over a wide BW is difficult for small antennas, as attempts to increase BW often result in a reduction of RE.
So using matching networks to improve BW can lead to increased losses, further decreasing RE. While these networks can broaden the impedance BW, they typically do so at the expense of efficiency due to the introduction of additional reactive elements that absorb power.
Designers often need to prioritize between BW and RE. For example, in narrowband applications (like certain communication systems), higher RE might be more important than BW. Conversely, in broadband applications, some efficiency might be sacrificed to achieve a wider operating range.
Question-part:
Based on all the above do I understand correctly that in order not to lose antenna RE by designing an impedance-matching circuit (e.g using 6 order filter) to cover the whole target band more wisely is to split the whole BW to e.g. 2 sub-BW and to switch between 2 e.g. 4 order filters?

FYI: "additional reactive elements that absorb power" -- this is a contradiction; reactance is conservative by definition.

A high Q antenna does not result in a narrow bandwidth. It just means it is highly capacitive. The antenna is not naturally resonant but, can be used to form an electrically resonant circuit when an inductor is added.
